# Node.js: How to write() on Write Stream 'finish' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm using Node.js streams to go through a text file line by line, make some transforms and output to a SVG file.

I am trying to write one last piece of data (`</svg>`) after the processing is done, however by the time the write stream emits the `finish` event,  attempting to `write()` will throw `Error: write after end`.

Is there an elegant way I can solve this?

**Note:** The input file is large (around 1GB) so there's no going around the `pipe()` method due to its I/O and memory management.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var split2 = require('split2');
var through2 = require('through2');

var read_stream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
var write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.svg');

write_stream.write('<svg>');
write_stream.on('finish', function() {
  this.write('</svg>'); // doesn't work
});

read_stream
  .pipe(split2())
  .pipe(through2.obj(function(line, encoding, next) {
     this.push(line);
     next();
  }))
  .pipe(write_stream);
```

### Solutions

Thank you [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4465244/jordan-honeycutt) & [pNre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795621/pnre) for helping me figuring this out.

#### Solution 1 (generic)

`pipe()` the write stream with the `end:false` option and manually `end()` the stream.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var split2 = require('split2');
var through2 = require('through2');

var read_stream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
var write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.svg');

write_stream.write('<svg>');

read_stream
  .pipe(split2())
  .pipe(through2.obj(function(line, encoding, next) {
     this.push(line);
     next();
  }))
  .pipe(write_stream, { end: false });

read_stream.on('end', function() {
  write_stream.end('</svg>');
});
```

#### Solution 2 (specific to `through`/`through2` transform streams)

[`through2`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) has a flush function that can be used to write the final data.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var split2 = require('split2');
var through2 = require('through2');

var read_stream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
var write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.svg');

write_stream.write('<svg>');

read_stream
  .pipe(split2())
  .pipe(through2.obj(function(line, encoding, next) {
    this.push(line);
    next();
  }, function(flush) {
    this.push('</svg>');
    flush();
  }))
  .pipe(write_stream);
```

Comment: Hello! I would suggest to extract your solutions from the question to the answers section.

Comment: @SlavaFominII can you give me some pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: @DanBurzo I believe that SlavaFominII is suggesting that you edit your Question and delete the  Solutions you appended. You can then create your own Answers to your Question or suggest edits via comments to Jordan's and/or pNre's Answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would seem that pipe closes the stream when it is finished.

The documentation at http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html states:

> By default end() is called on the destination when the source stream emits end, so that destination is no longer writable. Pass { end: false } as options to keep the destination stream open.
>
> This keeps writer open so that "Goodbye" can be written at the end.

```
reader.pipe(writer, { end: false });
reader.on('end', function() {
  writer.end('Goodbye\n');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review the question. I have added a clarifying note: the file is very large so I can't renounce `pipe()` lest it runs out of memory.

Comment: @Dan, I found what you're asking for on the site, I'll update my answer

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that in the documentation! Thanks, it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered creating a new stream to append the `</svg>` tag? 
[`through`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through) can help you with that:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var split2 = require('split2');
var through = require('through');

var read_stream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
var write_stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.svg');

write_stream.write('<svg>');
var tag = through(function write(data) {
    this.queue(data);
}, function end() {
    this.queue('</svg>');
});

read_stream.pipe(split2()).pipe(some_transform).pipe(tag).pipe(write_stream);
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I am using [`through2`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) for the transform, so I can just add a flush function to it. I knew that's available but somehow it didn't register in my conscious mind when I was searching for the solution :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an un-documented event called `'prefinish'`.
I have not used it though.

Answer (score 0):

Recently ran in to this issue and found a more elegant solution. There's a (well) documented `_flush` method on the native Transform stream.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback

The solution looks something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const split2 = require('split2')
const { Transform } = require('stream')

const input = fs.createReadStream('input.txt')
const output = fs.createWriteStream('output.svg')

class SVGWrapper extends Transform {
    constructor(){ this.push('<svg>') }

    _flush(done){ this.push('</svg>') }

    _transform(line, enc, next){
        this.push(line)
        next()
    }
}

input
    .pipe(split2())
    .pipe(new SVGWrapper)
    .pipe(output)
```